# How to access the selected text in a Flex mx:HTML control

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I am using mx:HTML to display HTML files. I want to get selected text like text area using `selectionBeginIndex,selectionEndIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution using html loader

```
html.htmlLoader.window.getSelection();
```